# How to display a low stock message for a WooCommerce variable product if backorders are allowed?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a custom message to display if one of my variable products stock is low. The problem i'm running into is if I enable backorders it causes the message to be displayed regardless of the quantity left. My $max_qty variable also does not appear in my custom message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    foreach( $available_variations as $i => $variation ) {
    // Get max qty that user can purchase
    $max_qty = $variation['max_qty'];

        //check if variation has stock or not 
        if ( $variation['is_in_stock'] && $max_qty < 5) {

            // Prepare availability html for stock available instance
            $availability_html = '<p class="stock in-stock" style="font-size: 1em">Hurry only ' . $max_qty . ' spots left on this day and time!' . '</p>';

        } 
    $available_variations[$i]['availability_html'] = $availability_html;
    }
```